# Como hago para que todas las imagenes de un carusel tengan las mismas medidas?

Tags: html, bootstrap

**Editado**

```
<section id="carousel">
<div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">     
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Marina Pez Vela.jpg" alt="Marina Pez Vela Quepos">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1><p class="text-body bg-light">Marina Pez Vela</p></h1>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/marinapv.jpg" alt="Marina">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Marina los Sueños CR</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: <section id="carousel">
    <div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: ¿Las imágenes reales tienen el mismo tamaño?. Si no son iguales, deberías decirle mediante `css` a la etiqueta `.img` el tamaño universal con la que quieres que se reflejen las imágenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tan cencillo como agregar un estilo a las imagenes ya sea linkando el archivo css o poniendo los estilos directo en tu archivo html ejemplo:

```
 <style>
 /*aqui le dices que las imagenes que estan dentro de la clase "carousel-item" todas tengan la misma altura y ancho*/ 
   .carousel-item img{ width:400px; height:400px;}//esto es un ejemplo aqui pones la medida que se adapte a tus nececidades
 </style>


<section id="carousel">
<div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-home" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">     
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/Marina Pez Vela.jpg" alt="Marina Pez Vela Quepos">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1><p class="text-body bg-light">Marina Pez Vela</p></h1>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/marinapv.jpg" alt="Marina">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Marina los Sueños CR</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, es que estoy empezando y no tenia ni idea como hacerlo pero ya quedo pura vida

Comment: si te sirvio la respuesta no olvides darle votar y marcarla como valida para que este entre las preguntas resueltas